How to interpret p-value?
I have a dataset of students, with mock-final and final tests.
With hypotheses,

$H_0: \mu_{mock-final} = \mu_{final}$
$H_0: \mu_{mock-final} \ \neq \mu_{final}$

I started with 2-tailed t-test ttest_rel(scores.mock_final, scores.final) with significance level of $5\%$ and got, $t-stat, p-val = -5.503, 1.796 * 10^{-7}$
Since, $\ p-val << 0.05$, I reject my null hypothesis i.e., $\ \mu_{mock-final} \neq \mu_{final}$.
Now, I frame the hypothesis like this,

$H_0: \mu_{mock-final} > \mu_{final}$
$H_0: \mu_{mock-final} \ < \mu_{final}$

and again, performed t-test but this time with alternate = 'greater'
ttest_rel(scores.mock_final, scores.final, alternate = 'greater')

and got, $t-stat, p-val = -5.503, 0.99999991$

Now, what should I interpret from this?
Should I have used alternate = 'less' w.r.t my Alternate hypothesis?
Thanks in advance.

First ask this question - are you trying to see if the mock exam scores are different than the actual exam?

@SeanRoberson Yes. To be specific, if mock test improved the final exam scores.

P-values can be interpreted in terms of the strength of evidence against the null hypothesis, but if you have an automatic rejection rule like you mention then you cannot use most of the evidential information for inference. See this open access chapter: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286

For a one-sided p-value the values close to 1 indicate that the observed effect was in the opposite direction from that expected by the null hypothesis. Your final scores were, on average, greater than the mock scores. Plot the data as a graph before running the stats tests so that the test results don't distort your perception of what the data say.

You should have equal as well in one-sided alternative $H_a$ (not $H_0$). Some intuition here.

@MichaelLew thanks for the reference, I haven't gone through it entirely, but the author is trying to explain it, really.
Also, thanks for the advice, but see that is the problem, if I use the data visualization or in fact the data itself to create the hypothesis, then my understanding of framing the hypothesis is already biased. I'll frame the hypothesis after looking at the data. But what I want is, to frame the hypothesis and then let my data tell me whether my hypothesis is right or wrong.

If you want to see if the real exam score is better than the mock, your alternative hypothesis is $H_A: \mu_{\text{mock}} < \mu_{\text{final}}$ so the alternate flag needs to be set to less.
Remember - the alternative hypothesis is the question you want answered!

Okay. So, you mean to say we try to hypothesize in such a way that we surely reject the null hypothesis by getting p-value less than significance level, because that give strong evidence. Whereas the other part gives "not enough evidence", is my understanding correct?
